# RSA generation of private key using public key

Tags: encryption, rsa

In RSA private key generation

```
e*d ≡ 1 mod φ
```

`e` is public, also n is public. How to prove mathematically, generation of private key `d` is not possible using the same equation and public key `e`

Comment: Obtaining the private key from the public key is not impossible, just computationally intractable.

Comment: why do you need to prove this? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Now that I reread your question, I have no idea what you are asking. Are you asking how to prove that generation of $d$ given only $e$ and $N$ is not possible? Or are you asking how to prove that it is not possible to generate $d$ using the equation $ed\equiv 1\bmod{\phi}$ (where presumably you are given $\phi$ since it is part of the equation)?

Comment: logically or mathematically want to prove it is impossible

Comment: Prove what is impossible? Are you given $e$ and $N$ or $e$ and $\phi$?

Comment: e and ϕ given? Even if we know N. it is not possible. rt?

Comment: With $\phi$ and $e$ given, computing $d$ is easy. Given $e$ and $N$ it is computationally infeasible (not impossible, a quantum computer could do it).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't impossible. Otherwise, we wouldn't have to keep increasing key sizes of our RSA keys, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/what-is-the-history-of-recommended-rsa-key-sizes) for the history.

As stated in a comment, it is believed to be computationally hard. Though, even that has never been proven.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this equation you must know:

- the factorisation of the public modulus $n=p \times q$,
- **either:**
- the value of the Euler totient $\phi(n)=(p-1)\times (q-1)=n-(p+q)+1$

There are no other alternatives to solve this equation. This is linked by the structure of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n \equiv \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_q$, which represents the intractability of the factorization problem.